# Spinner not updating properly in ViewPager inside Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I have `ViewPager` inside `DialogFragment` and I have three `Fragment` in the `ViewPager` each having a spinner which updates from the API calls.Whenever the fragment is initiated its get spinner values from the server
Now the problem is when ever user swipe the pager let say i swipe from page 1 to page 2 than the spinner value gets updated from page 3
I know that `ViewPager` has `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(MAX_LIMIT);` but minimum value is 1

Is there any way or work around for this problem ?

I have refer this [Example](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)

Comment: you seem to be an older member of this site, don't you? where is your code?

Comment: Its a whole lot of code. I am just briefing the problem here

Comment: great of all, i recently came across the same problem. and what i found was to use Local Broadcast stuff, which i found really cumbersome, and i had to choose other way.

Comment: did you tried `setUserVisibleHint()` ?

Comment: Nop...i didn't tried @VivekMishra

Comment: then give it a try, it helps in these conditions

Comment: bit confused with the question. Do you mean you have 3 service calls from  each of your fragments ? And the result of a service call from 3rd fragment by mistake gets updated on the 2nd fragment ?

Comment: Result of a service call from 3rd fragment  gets updated on the 2nd fragment

Comment: Nop it did not worked @VivekMishra